# twitter typeahead on select send to php

Tags: php, twitter, typeahead

I'm trying to get the selected value from typeahead and send it to php as a variable, can someone help?

Here is what I tried

```
    $('#person').bind('typeahead:selected', submitChoice);
      function submitChoice(){
        var choicePerson=$('#person').val();
        $.ajax({
          data: {choicePerson : choicePerson},
          url: 'search-users.php',
          type: 'POST',
        });
      }
```

And the php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['choicePerson'])) {
$choice = $_POST['choicePerson'];
echo $choice;
};
?>
```

In the php I just want to echo and see if it works and then I will do some if statements with the variable.

Comment: which problem do you have with your code? Can you share a little more like the sources for typeahead? Have you checked the $_POST array server-side ( a print_r($_POST) is enough)? Have a look at your developer tools, network tab to check the data sent by POST. You should use submitChoice with arguments and take the selected value from the second argument according to the custom events documentation https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events.

Comment: The source of typeahead is another php script with mysql table that populates names and id's, now, I want to get the id of the selected person and then match from another table.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I made it as follows:

```
    $('#person').bind('typeahead:selected', submitChoice);
  function submitChoice(person){
    var person=$('#person').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'search-users.php',
      data: {person:person},
    });
  }
```